# "Carbon snakes" - what physico-chemical process causes the exothermic response?

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base

Making a "carbon snake" requires the mixing of strong sulphuric acid with sugar, as explained [in this about.chemistry webpage](http://chemistry.about.com/od/chemistrydemonstrations/a/acidsugardemo.htm) - the reaction causes rapid dehydration of the sugar and produces steam in the process, which expands and forms the 'carbon snake', following the incomplete chemical reaction:

$\ce{C12H22O11 + H2SO4 → 12C + 11H2O}$  + mixture of excess unreacted water, sulfur dioxide and acid (and presumably a bundle of other chemicals)

My question is, what physical/chemical processes cause this rapid dehydration and exothermic reaction?

Comment: Too busy to leave an answer but check this document out: http://ncsu.edu/project/chemistrydemos/Thermochem/DehydrationSugar.pdf

Comment: Your equation is not balanced; you did not account for where the sulfur in sulfuric acid went. Some of the sulfur is oxidized into sulfur dioxide if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Dissenter yes, I saw that too (that's what I get for copying that formula from the website - clarified it as an incomplete generalised formula)

Comment: does any one knows the ingridients of the commercial snakes

Answer (score 2):

$\ce{C_mH_{2n}O_n -> m C + n H2O}$

The hydration reaction of sulfuric acid acts as the driving force because it is highly exothermic (95.33 kJ/mol H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>).